# Write access violation при заполнении двумерного массива

Tags: c

```
int i,j,m,n;
double** array;
int main(void)
{
    printf("strings pls:");
    scanf_s("%d",&m);
    printf("columns pls:");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {

        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            array[i][j] = rand();
        }
        printf("&lf", array[i][j]);
    }
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А память под массив кто выделять будет?

Comment: И еще, строки в матрице - это все же `rows`, а не `strings`.

Answer (score 3):

Просто не выделена память под массив...
Перед тем как писать в `array`, нудно выделить память. Примерно

```
array = malloc(m*sizeof(double*));
for(int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    array[i] = malloc(n*sizeof(double));
```

И еще - вот это

```
printf("&lf", array[i][j]);
```

будет выводить просто `&lf` :)

Comment: Не получается(( Как будет выглядеть код

Answer (score 0):

```
и все ровно ошибка(
int m,n,i,j;
double **arrayl;
int main()
{
printf("strings pls:");
scanf_s("%d",&m);   
printf("columns pls:");
scanf_s("%d", &n);
arrayl = (double**)calloc(n,sizeof(double*));
for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
{
    arrayl = (double**)calloc(m, sizeof(double));
}
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <n; j++)
        {
            arrayl[i][j] = rand() % 30;
        }
    }
    printf("&lf", arrayl[i][j]);

    getchar();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: поделом. Вам выше дали код - сравните с Вашим.

Comment: а как вывести массив?

Comment: распределите сначала под него память, как показано в ответе выше